# Can I reference the result of one part of a select clause in another part of the same select clause?

Tags: sql, hive, hiveql

Is it possible to do something that would accomplish the same thing as?

```
select
user_id as uid,
uid/2 as random,
from table_name
```

Comment: No, this is not valid SQL.  SQL does not guarantee the order of evaluation of expressions in the `SELECT` clause.

Comment: Is it possible to accomplish the same thing without saying `select user_id/2 as random from table_name`?

Comment: Select uid/2 from (select userid as uid from table)